Can I connect an ice maker to a bathroom supply?
I just bought a new fridge and will be installing a new ice maker outlet box in the kitchen to feed the water/ice maker. On the other side of my wall is a shower, and a little further down the same wall is my bathroom vanity/sink. It would be simpler to run off the cold shower line since it is right behind my fridge. However, I love having access to my plumbing.
Would it be weird to run it from my toilet shut off valve or vanity shut off valve and back into the wall to the fridge? Easier access in case I wish to modify the connection in the future. I haven't really seen this done before so it may not be up to code, just curious what people think of this method?
Alternatively I could put in an access panel which may not be the worst idea for the back of a shower anyway.

You can run the line from any of the options you have listed. You'll want to pick the easiest one with the least amount of repair work afterards. You shouldn't run the line from any of the existing shutoff valves. It should have it's own separate shutoff valve.

An ice maker outlet box includes a shutoff valve, so there's no need for an extra shutoff. Just plumb it directly to the cold line.
